# XML attribute order

Tags: c#

I have this code for writing my XML

```
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = ("\t");

        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("sample.xml",settings);
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Report", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","rd", null, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();

        writer.Close();
```

The code above yields this output in my **sample.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" />
```

However, what I would like as an output would be this:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

I tried re-order my codes but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: According to spec, the order of xml namespace elements shouldn't matter here.  Is there a functional problem?  You might find support tricky because there doesn't appear to be a mandate to write them in order.

Comment: Whoa. It suddenly worked! Earlier I tried to modify the attribute of Report in my RDLC and it gave me some weird error on the RDLC Designer. Thanks mate! silly me.